# Counting occurences of campaigns in products in Golang

Tags: go

I have the code below

```
    teasers := []*models.TeaserCount{}
    var teaser models.TeaserCount

    for _, product := range ProductResponse.Products {
        added := false
        if len(product.Campaign.Id) > 0 {
            if len(teasers) > 0 {
                for _, teaserCount := range teasers {
                    if teaserCount.Id == product.Campaign.Id {
                        fmt.Println(teaserCount.Id, teaserCount.Count+1)
                        teaserCount.Count++
                        added = true
                        break
                    }
                }

                if added == false {
                    teaser = models.TeaserCount{
                        Id:    product.Campaign.Id,
                        Count: 0,
                    }

                    teasers = append(teasers, &teaser)
                }
            } else {
                teaser = models.TeaserCount{
                    Id:    product.Campaign.Id,
                    Count: 0,
                }

                teasers = append(teasers, &teaser)
            }
        }
    }
```

What I want to do, is to count how many times each campaign occured in product
I want to have an array of objects including campaign id and occurences

Results that I get is that each and every single object in array is the same(the last one added by append)

How is that so, the behavior seems quite strange to me, maybe that has to do with pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending a pointer to the local loop variable, which changes on each iteration:

```
// This pointer will always point to the current/last loop iteration value
teasers = append(teasers, &teaser)
```

You should instead either append a pointer to a copy:

```
temp := teaser
teasers = append(teasers, &temp)
```

Or a pointer to the element of the slice:

```
for i, product := range ProductResponse.Products {
    // ...
    teasers = append(teasers, &ProductResponse.Products[i])
```

If you choose the former, the pointer will be to a copy dedicated to `teasers`, whereas if you do the latter, it will be a pointer to the element of the original slice (meaning if the value in the slice changes, that will be reflected in `teasers`).